# Hook on product page view in Drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, google-analytics

I want to run page view event from tracking with Google Analytics/piwik on Drupal commerce using my own Module.

Which hook can i use in Drupal commerce to run my own code? I just need to find the best hook that is called when page view is fired for the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since product displays are nodes, [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes tried that. But it is not working. I even put die() in the hook but it is not getting called.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your module. Ensure your module is enabled, check your function names, clear your caches, etc.

Comment: I am able to call code on other hooks of commerce module from my module. Only that MYMODULE_node_view() is not getting called with product view. :(. Following is the sample code of the function: `function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
            $node->content['my_extra_content'] = array(
                 "#markup"=> '<div class="test">My extra content!</div>',
                 "#weight"=> 100
              );   
         return $node;
   
}`

Comment: Got it to work. Was missing on clearing cache.